# Angular - How to filter data being displayed using ng-repeat based on select/options pick by user?

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

Data should be displayed based on the options field (by ng-repeating) (please see below). For example, if user picks 'The Best Company Denim', only users belonging to that company should be displayed. I tried out filter but that doesn't seem to work, I have tried to write a function that checks for the chosen option which works but then I don't know how to display that (tried to loop through the users array and add to a new array, then ng-repeat through that array). anyone can help? Thanks!!!!

```
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
 <select ng-model="selectedAccount" ng-options="account.name for account in companies" ng-change="change()">
 </select>
   <div ng-repeat="company in companies">
    <div ng-repeat="user in company.users">
        <p>{{user.firstName}} | filter: 'selectedAccount'</p>
    </div>
   <div>
  </div>

app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.companies = [{
        name: 'The Best Company Denim',
        users: [{
            firstName: 'Alex',
            lastName: 'D',
            number: 1234
        }, {
            firstName: 'Sarah',
            lastName: 't',
            number: 14
        }, {
            firstName: 'J',
            lastName: 'd',
            number: 07
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'The Best Company Elegant',
        users: [{
            firstName: 'Alx',
            lastName: 'B',
            number: 1234
        }, {
            firstName: 'Seth',
            lastName: 'w',
            number: 12
        }, {
            firstName: 'J.S',
            lastName: 'B',
            number: 7
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'The Best Company by Julia',
        users: [{
            firstName: 'Aleddddx',
            lastName: 'l',
            number: 1234
        }, {
            firstName: 'Maggy',
            lastName: 'n',
            number: 1
        }, {
            firstName: 'Ja',
            lastName: 'Key',
            number: 123
        }]
    }]
$scope.change = function() {
   var x = "";
   for (var i = 0; i < $scope.selectedAccount.users.length; i++) {
       console.log($scope.selectedAccount.users[i])
       x += $scope.selectedAccount.users[i]
   }
   return x;
```

}
   });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, you're using `filter` in a incorrect way.

[**Filter**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) is used for *arrays*. So you must use like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="element in array | filter: param">
```

In your specific case, you want to filter the elements in array by the `name` property. So you should write the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="company in companies | filter: { name: selectedAccount }">
```

Also, in your `ng-options`, in order to bind the name of company to the `selectedAccount` *variable* use the `as` *syntax*:

```
<select ng-model="selectedAccount" ng-options="account.name as account.name for account in companies">
</select>
```

---

Please refer to the following snippet:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('appCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.companies = [{
        name: 'The Best Company Denim',
        users: [{
          firstName: 'Alex',
          lastName: 'D',
          number: 1234
        }, {
          firstName: 'Sarah',
          lastName: 't',
          number: 14
        }, {
          firstName: 'J',
          lastName: 'd',
          number: 7
        }]
      }, {
        name: 'The Best Company Elegant',
        users: [{
          firstName: 'Alx',
          lastName: 'B',
          number: 1234
        }, {
          firstName: 'Seth',
          lastName: 'w',
          number: 12
        }, {
          firstName: 'J.S',
          lastName: 'B',
          number: 7
        }]
      }, {
        name: 'The Best Company by Julia',
        users: [{
          firstName: 'Aleddddx',
          lastName: 'l',
          number: 1234
        }, {
          firstName: 'Maggy',
          lastName: 'n',
          number: 1
        }, {
          firstName: 'Ja',
          lastName: 'Key',
          number: 123
        }]
      }];
    });
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <div>
    <select ng-model="selectedAccount" ng-options="account.name as account.name for account in companies">
    </select>
    <hr>
    <div>
      Selected company: {{selectedAccount}}
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div ng-repeat="company in companies | filter: { name: selectedAccount }">
      <div ng-repeat="user in company.users">
        <p>{{user.firstName}}</p>
      </div>
      <div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Note** that you even don't need to call the `(ng-change)` anymore.